# Laravel 7 - Logout specific user after updating their information

Tags: laravel, logout, laravel-7

As an Admin, I can register users. There's no way to register their own, only I can register them. So they can login with email and password that I given. But the problem is when I change their any of email or password they will be logged out immediately. How can I do that?

I tried this, but its not working-

```
$getUser = User::where('id', $id)->first();
Auth::logout($getUser);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cheap way:**

```
$user = Auth::user();

$secondUser = User::find(1);
Auth::setUser($secondUser);
Auth::logout();

Auth::setUser($user);
```

**Long way:**

Create a field in users table such as `password_is_active` 1,0 with defaults 1.

Create middleware `checkUserPasswordIsActive` if fail call `Auth::logout();`